# How to send hash of hash of array items to csv

Tags: arrays, windows, perl, csv, hash

Hash of Hash of values were printing correctly to csv but hash of hash of array values are messing up my csv file. Please find my code below which is not working.

```
<    use strict;
     use warnings;
     use Data::Dumper;

     my %student_hash;
     my $student_report = "StudentReport.csv";

     %student_hash = (
            'RollNummber1' => {
                               'studentname' => 'Boris',
                               'address' => ['Vietnam',
                                             'local'
                                            ],
                               'DOB' => '5june2000'

                               },
            'RollNummber2' => {
                               'studentname' => 'John',
                               'address' => [ 
                                             '4th/floor',
                                             'Culverdown/Street',
                                             'WestHam',
                                             'UK.',
                                            ],
                               'DOB' => '2feb2000'

                               },
            'RollNummber3' => {
                               'studentname' => 'Karen',
                               'DOB' => '5march2000'

                              }
           );

          print "StudentHash:".Dumper(\%student_hash);

          open(my $fh, '>', $student_report) or die("Couldn't open ile");
          print $fh "DOB \t,ADDRESS \t,NAME \t\n";

          foreach my $key(keys %student_hash){
           foreach my $secondkeys (keys %{$student_hash{$key}}){

             if($secondkeys =~ /DOB || studentname/) {
               print $fh "$student_hash{$key}{$secondkeys} \t,"; } 
             if($secondkeys =~ /address/) {
               print $fh Dumper $student_hash{$key}{$secondkeys} }; 
        }
    print $fh "\n";
 }
 close($fh);>
```

If I comment out printing the array part then the code works fine.Can someone please suggest how to print the array elements into csv either in one cell or in multiple cells.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm) - you can either use `print` if you've got an array reference to print. (It handles quoting for you).

Or you can use `column_names` to set the column ordering, and `print_hr` to output a hash ref in that order.

It looks like you're not worried about `RollNumber` so you can cheat and do:

```
foreach my $student ( values %student_hash ) { 

}
```

To iterate. I'm unclear what you're trying to do with `address`. But a simple `join` would probably do the trick there. (either on linefeed or whitespace, depending on the desired output).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my %student_hash = (
    'RollNummber1' => {
        'studentname' => 'Boris',
        'address'     => [ 'Vietnam', 'local' ],
        'DOB'         => '5june2000'

    },
    'RollNummber2' => {
        'studentname' => 'John',
        'address' => [ '4th/floor', 'Culverdown/Street', 'WestHam', 'UK.', ],
        'DOB'     => '2feb2000'

    },
    'RollNummber3' => {
        'studentname' => 'Karen',
        'DOB'         => '5march2000'

    }
);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => ',', eol => "\n" } );
$csv->column_names( 'studentname', 'DOB', 'address' );
foreach my $student ( values %student_hash ) {
    if ( defined $student -> {address} ) { 
        $student -> {address} = join (" ", @{$student->{address}});
    }

    $csv->print_hr( \*STDOUT, $student );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use module.But I shall try this join tip .I will let you know Thank you

Comment: It really is the easiest way of 'doing' CSV data. Of course, given a multi-line address, that's not necessarily the right way to go in the first place. Have you considered XML output?

Comment: Actually once i am able to print the multi line address aswell in csv I thought to perform sort so that the order will be student name then DOB then address . I am struggling to print this multi line address and i have to do it without using module.I shall try printing in XML as suggested. thanks

Comment: Hi I tried outputting it to xml and i am able to manage the sort order but I am struggling with the same problem, printing arrays to csv :(

Comment: Join worked for me . but it doesnot print the entire thing in one cell it prints to the next cell . thanks

Comment: modifying join to    $student -> {address} = join ("\n\t\t ", @{$student->{address}}); Worked perfectly .....